# Add image/photo as Blob to a geopandas dataframe and then save to a geopackage *.gpkg

Tags: geopandas, spatialite, image, geopackage, binary

Trying to switch from doing this through spatialite, and fully containing it within geopandas.

I have a file with the image's file locations in it, and loop through them all.  Open each image and add it as a column in the geopandas datafile, which works just fine.

```
    FeaturesGdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
    rowid = 1
    for fid, feature, img_file_name in enumerate(features):
        img_data = b''
        with open(img_file_name , 'rb') as img_file: 
            img_data = img_file.read()

        newline = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'rowid':[rowid],                                                       
                     'geometry':geometry.Point(feature.geometry.x,   
                         feature.geometry.y, feature.geometry.z), 
                     'node_id':fid, 
                     'target_image':img_data}, 
                     crs="EPSG:4326") 

        rowid=rowid+1
        gdfs = [FeaturesGdf, newline]
        FeaturesGdf = pd.concat(gdfs, ignore_index=True)

    outputGdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(FeaturesGdf, crs="EPSG:4326")
    outputGdf.to_file(str(out_path) + "/geopackage.gpkg", layer="image_features", driver="GPKG")
```

If I "view" the dataframe, I get

```
   target_image  
0   b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\...  
1   b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\...
```

however, in the last line "to_file" gives me this error `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'bytes'>`

The only solutions I have found so far for this error is to convert it to a string... but either I'm not converting it correctly or it doesn't work in this case.

I also tried going directly from FeatureGdf.to_file, but get this error:
`TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x00000215ACC7A080>' as a data type`

this is how it should look when opened in QGIS (via the old way):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- encode in base64 target_image then,
- decode as when you view in your Dataframe target_image is in binary mode : the b'' encapsulation.

So before exporting to file, apply to all Dataframe:

```
import base64
for i in range(len(outputGdf)):
    outputGdf.iloc[i, outputGdf.columns.get_loc('target_image')] = base64.b64encode(outputGdf.iloc[i]['target_image']).decode()
```

Finally you can export to GPKG.

Note: some base64 viewer handle to view the problem.

It can be viewed in QGIS with :
'base64:'|| "target_image"

[image]

I hope it can help !

Comment: Thanks! It's been awhile since I worked on this, and definitely hadn't solved it... but will utilize your answer when I do.

Answer (score 1):

In Sylvain's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/464021/56220), a base64 string is written. If you want to output a BLOB, try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

outputGdf.to_file("geopackage.gpkg", schema={"geometry": "Point", "properties": OrderedDict([("rowid", "int"), ("node_id", "int"), ("target_image", "bytes")])})
```

It's possible to pass a normal dict instead of an OrderedDict when the order of attribute columns does not matter.